# Remote image causes SSL warning in I.E

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, amazon-s3

Our e-commerce site has a problem with remote image URLs in IE.  Our purchase page is SSL, but it displays a product image, which we pull from Amazon S3.  As such, IE throws an SSL warning and refuses to load the image.  Is there any way to get around this?

Thanks

Comment: Store the images locally and serve them through SSL instead?

Comment: could you be more precise about the nature of the error message?

Comment: Amazon S3 should support SSL, so wouldn't using https:// when you link to the image work?

Comment: Just found the SSL option for S3.  That will fix the issue.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized that Amazon provides S3 SSL support.  D'oh!  Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

No. Unless you're loading ALL the content via HTTPS, you're going to get the "some content is not secure" warnings. There's nothing you can do to suppress it, as providing a mechanism for suppression would be a major security hole.

Either you serve up everything in the page via HTTPS, or live with the warnings.